# SDK level problems in developer console

Tags: android, sdk, permissions, downgrade

so im working on a small utility app to get started on the play store and ive come across a few issues which has led me up to this

It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 1 (target SDK 23) to version 2 (target SDK 19).

for a small app like this it would be irritating for it to only be available on newer versions considering it doesnt require much. I cant remove the apk nor can i delete the project entirely so the question is should i just publish it for sdk 23 or should i just leave the project alone and make an entirely new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken. Target SDK means the latest supported version. But it would still allow applications be installed on newer versions. Min SDK version means the earliest supported version.

If Target SDK is set to 23, and update comes out, which is 24, then app would still work on that device, however, whatever new features SDK 24 brings, won't be available.

You can read more at [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: ok so it will work for older devices as long as the minimum sdk level is for example 14 and the target sdk level can be 23 right?

Comment: Yes. When creating new project, notice that it only asks what your minimum SDK version is, and provides percentages of supported devices based on minimum SDK version only. Target SDK does not affect supported devices, but it affects features available to you.

Comment: alright thanks for the help now i just need to figure out what im gonna do with actionbardrawertoggle not working cause its not letting me compile v4 anymore

Comment: That's different issue and you should ask new question.